# Command / Method to find the up-time of SSH server daemon & Nginx

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, ssh, uptime

I am looking for a method / Linux command to get the up-time of the `open-ssh` server and `Nginx` server running on my Ubuntu system. I want to know the up-time for calculating some internal statistics. I am looking for something similar to `mysqladmin status` command.

Thanks

Comment: You probably want this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7870/how-to-check-how-long-a-process-has-been-running

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well there isn't really an uptime of openssh.  you can check that it is active or how many connections it has.  Or can grab the last time it was restarted by looking at `/var/run/sshd.pid`

```
ls -l /var/run/sshd.pid
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4 2012-12-15 21:26 /var/run/sshd.pid
```

That file is updated when the daemon starts/restarts. So you can calculate based on that.

For nginx you can install the status module (http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpStubStatusModule)  and then use that to get some information, but alas uptime doesn't look to be there.  Could probably use the same idea of looking at the nginx pid files, but that will just tell you since the last restart etc. and not 100% indicative of uptime.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following answer for getting that information from ps.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731234/how-to-get-the-start-time-of-a-long-running-linux-process

You'll need to parse that output (awk, Perl, or Python come to mind).

Alternatively you might be able to use the ctime of (for example)

```
/proc/PID_OF_NGINX_MASTER_PROCESS
```

but I'm not 100% sure about that.